# Dynamic checkbox not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, checkbox

I am running a React Native app.
I want my checkboxes to be dynamic. The below code makes the checkbox dynamic but I am unable to get my desired format.

`App.js`

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, key: 'Read', type: 'HeartRate',  checked: false },
        { id: 2, key: 'Write', type: 'HeartRate',  checked: false },
        { id: 3, key: 'Read', type: 'BodyMassIndex',  checked: false },
        { id: 4, key: 'Write', type: 'BodyMassIndex',  checked: false }
            ]
        }
   }


onCheckChanged = (id) => {
    const data = this.state.data;

    const index = data.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
    data[index].checked = !data[index].checked;
    this.setState(data);
}


render() {
    return (
              {
                this.state.data.map((item,key) => 
                <View  style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <Text style={styles.modalText}> {item.type} </Text>
               <CheckBox title={item.key} key={key}  checked={item.checked} onPress={()=>this.onCheckChanged(item.id)}/>
               </View>
               )
            }
    )
}
```

The output of the above code is:

[image]

But I want it to be in this format. "HearRate", "Read" and "Write" are all in 1 row.
How can I achieve this? Any help would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to format your checkbox data before rendering it. You can format it like following

```
const formattedData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'HeartRate',
    options: [
      { key: 'Read', checked: false },
      { key: 'Write', checked: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'BodyMassIndex',
    options: [
      { key: 'Read', checked: false },
      { key: 'Write', checked: false },
    ],
  },
];
```

and if you want to achieve the above output that you mentioned, you can render all the items like this -

```
{formattedData.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',  marginBottom: 20 }}>
              <Text>{item.type}</Text>
              {item.options.map((val) => {
                return (
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: 10, }}>
                    // this should be your checkbox
                    <View style={styles.checkbox} />
                    <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>{val.key}</Text>
                  </View>
                );
              })}
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      })}
```

You will get the output like this,

[image]

Finally, [here](https://snack.expo.io/@saad-bashar/dynamic-checkbox) is a working demo for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
onCheckChanged = (item, key) => {                 
    const newData = {...this.state.data}; // Deep cloning data
    newData[index].checked = !newData[index].checked; // Mutate the value
    this.setState(newData); // Reset state to reflect on screen
}


render() {
    return (
            {
                this.state.data.map((item,key) => 
                // Remove warning by adding `key` prop here
                <View key={`${key}`}  ...>
                  ...
                 <CheckBox ... 
                     checked={item.checked} 
                     onPress={()=>this.onCheckChanged(item, key)}
                 />
               </View>
               )
           }
    )
}
```

Comment: it displays in the same format. see 2nd picture in my question. i want that format.